# Azure AD B2C and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, authentication, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have Azure B2C setup using OpenID Connect. I also have a local SQL Server database. I know that the id_token (Jtw token) can contain the logged-in user's email, so my question is how do I get the user's email from the id_token and use it to run queries?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to  secure your local Sql with AAD B2C ?

Comment: My goal is to return data from my local Sql when the user login, so if I can do that by securing my Sql, then yes.

Comment: I think we need a bit more context - are you connecting a web application to B2C using OpenID Connect, and this web application needs to query the database?  Or are you trying to let users connect to the database directly (using something like SSMS or SQLCMD) and you want their authentication to be based on B2C?

Comment: The former. I have a web app that connects to B2C using OpenID Connect, and I need to get the user's email from the authentication process to query the database. Basically, when the user is authenticated, I want to show info from the database on the page they get redirected to.

Comment: Is this an ASP.NET application or one on a different platform?

Comment: This is a .NET Core application

Comment: In B2C email is not the same as username or the same as log in name or the same as user id.   You may want to test with many Azure B2C user types before you key in on email.  Email is NOT a unique key or unique user id in B2C.    Using oid – or the object id user guid in the B2C AD tenant is a better unique key if you are trying to map users at runtime.  Your b2C tenant id plus the guid like user id is a better user id key than email.  Just an FYI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From within an ASP.NET Core application, you can do the following:

```cs
var user = HttpContext.User;
var emailsClaim = user.FindFirst("emails");
var emails = JArray.Parse(emailsClaim);
var firstEmail = emails[0].value;
//firstEmail == “bob@gmail.com” based up the sample token
```

[Sample Token](https://jwt.ms/#id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ilg1ZVhrNHh5b2pORnVtMWtsMll0djhkbE5QNC1jNTdkTzZRR1RWQndhTmsifQ.eyJleHAiOjE1MjEyMzIzMzUsIm5iZiI6MTUyMTIyODczNSwidmVyIjoiMS4wIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2dpbi5taWNyb3NvZnRvbmxpbmUuY29tLzgwMDMzZGZkLTZlYWItNDJjNC1iZGYyLTRlMjIzZDRiMzk2Zi92Mi4wLyIsInN1YiI6IjU0ZDg0YWMwLTdjOWUtNDFlNC05MWQ3LTM0OTZjYzgyOGI0OSIsImF1ZCI6ImQzOWJmOGJmLWRjMGEtNDdjNi04YzU1LWZiMGFhZGE1M2QyMyIsIm5vbmNlIjoiZGVmYXVsdE5vbmNlIiwiaWF0IjoxNTIxMjI4NzM1LCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE1MjEyMjg3MzUsImVtYWlscyI6WyJib2JAZ21haWwuY29tIl0sInRmcCI6IkIyQ18xX1Rva2VuVmlld2VyIn0.rQKsX0YU-Zwz1dptM23IcYtwnZEvb6EjX4mfuMy7utbSSSxFPM36oe0qw9MMUvTzEgS3NrRv578bo5MH4wIwWqWzShd-PjK7I-uJJHk12B1WXWDubqUCejVUIckrC7wRBA_c5ibE4UptnLV-D0PIoNi6zLn5o73g0M4qp-8wXVGWx5G-k8DPgYk3OQ9zub8U2fOLoUq8y0EtzcioFXQdvO1PTvDW19Ieig55JZB3MFNpN2vWIraO5PdCfuGPqDF27V81h-vJOap2y7tiTQ_LyC-Ut4VuzJG1aWn--2S5LBVwfEOTb1DZd9_uEC3iMJp9MkxneM7LKv2lIkfXbYZtWg)

Comment: What is the value of json in this case?

Comment: See the sample token link.  See the emails claim... @younggrasshopper

Comment: So doesn't the 3rd line need to be `var emails = JArray.Parse(emailsClaim);` instead?